# How to draw a line under a circle with Mapbox's Annotation plugin?

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am trying to display two circles and a line connecting them using the Mapbox Android SDK (7.0.0) and Annotations plugin (0.4.0). The line should be drawn when the user taps on two the two circles. Ideally, the line should appear underneath the circles. If I declare the line and circle managers like this:

```
lineManager = new LineManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style);
circleManager = new CircleManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style);
```

The `circle.OnClickListener` is never called. If I declare the line and circle managers like this:

```
circleManager = new CircleManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style);
lineManager = new LineManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style);
```

The `circle.OnClickListener` is called, but the resulting line is drawn on top of the circles, like this:

[image]

Instead of like this:

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Is there a way to tell the map to draw the line underneath the circles? Or is there an issue with the order I am declaring the LineManager and CircleManager.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here are my build.gradle files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nocompany.datacollectionapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
} 
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Results in a gradle build error of `Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct and regarding the

> The circle.OnClickListener is never called.

This is most likely [already resolved.](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/815) You can test the solution with the [com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-annotation#getting-started), but remember to include Sonatype repository reference.

Comment: Adding `maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }` and `implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT'` to the respective build.gradle files gives me a `Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT` error. Is there something else I must do?

Comment: Are you sure you've specified the classpath in the correct `build.gradle` file? The `SNAPSHOT` resolves for me with no issues https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7/0.5.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: I've added my gradle files and the error I am receiving. My apologies if I am doing something silly, I have never used sonatype.

Comment: The snapshot repository reference has to be specified in the other `repository` block under `allprojects`.